# How to restrict access to a non-drupal url on a site's domain?

Tags: 7, users

So, I've just run into this issue with a drupal 7 site that I am maintaining. Access to the mailing list URL www.XXXmysite.com/mailman/listinfo is accessible to the general public. Is there someway of restricting access to this URL through drupal's permissions? This isn't obvious how to do because the mailman program isn't a part of drupal, I'm not sure where the program actually runs from, but the url is mapped from the site's domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. It sounds like your web server has the mailman web interface alias to that path. If that's the case, Drupal is never evoked so it wouldn't have any say on how that request is handled (i.e. **index.php?q=mailmain/listinfo** isn't executed for page handling).

You'll need look at configuring your web server to remove your alias, or remove it for your hostname.